# postgresql returning updated column

Tags: postgresql, insert

I'd like to log any table. 
So I need to know what columns changed.
Could you give me some tips for hoping result?
I only want updated column.

table: test

```
col1 |col2 | col3
------+------+------
 a    | a    | a
 b    | b    | b
```

Query:

```
UPDATE test SET col2='x' WHERE col1='a'RETURNING *;
```

result:

```
 col1 | col2 | col3 
------+------+------
 a    | x    | a
```

expected result:

```
| col2 | 
+------+
| x    |
```

Comment: Do you want to build an audit trail ? http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger

Comment: Why do you expect a single column when you specify `*` which means "all columns"?

Answer (score 3):

`Returning *` works much like a select statement. You can specify column names, e.g. `returning col2`.

Also, note Marcello's comment: audits are better done using triggers.